# Keep a DOM node/element alive in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I was wondering if there is a way to keep a DOM node alive and available the next time a component mounts after it has unmounted?

I'm curious about this in general, because this question has come up for me more than once, so I would love answers for the general case instead of only solutions to my particular problem this time.

Just for example though, in my current case, I use the Adobe Embed PDF api to embed a PDF in a page on my website. When the user navigates to another page on my website through a  and then navigates back to the PDF page, the PDF is gone and there is just an empty div in its place again as per the template.  The Adobe API takes an empty div and renders a PDF inside of it. Once I navigate away and back, I'm left with the empty div again. I could re-render it every time I arrive at the page, but this is quite slow and I'd rather just have it cached.

As another example, Google reCAPTCHA also renders to an element that I would have liked to keep alive so that I could only render it once like in Google's reCAPTCHA examples, so that I would know it would work since it would be sticking to the way things were done in the examples. However in that case I ended up just using the vue-recaptcha library, so I didn't have to understand or implement a solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in [KeepAlive](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html) component that might do what you want? Though I'm not sure if it also caches the DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

To keep alive the routes, You can add the `<keep-alive>` component as a wrapper of `<router-view>` and [`include`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#include-exclude) the required route names which you want to cache.

In the below example, I am just using `pdfview` as a route name.

```
<keep-alive include="pdfview">
    <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

**Important Note :** If You think that pdf will contains the static data then this approach is fine but if it will be containing dynamic or real time data then There is only disadvantage of using `<keep-alive>` as this component will be kept in memory and therefore their state is saved and not reset. You will loose lifecycle hooks like `created`, `mounted`, etc. since the component is not being rebuilt from scratch anymore.

Then you have to use the life cycle hooks of Cached Instances listed [`here`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#lifecycle-of-cached-instance).

Comment: Thanks for the lead! I'm getting this error, but can hopefully figure it out from here. <router-view> can no longer be used directly inside <transition> or <keep-alive>.
Use slot props instead:
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </keep-alive>
</router-view>

Comment: The PDF iframe wasn't working after re-routing for me when I used the code from my last comment that was suggested in the error message. Using the answer here, although perhaps not clean and ideal worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406235/3470632